# Stack Overflow style expanding tag information?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-data

Regular users of Stack Overflow will have noticed that when you hover over a tag here, a box below the tag will animate open to show more information about it. One of my bosses wants every `td` tag within one column in a `table` on our site to do the same thing. Obviously, there are ways to do this using just jQuery to animate open a `div` or something. Is there a plugin specifically for this that anyone thinks would be better, or a specific way that it should be done using jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If i were to approach this problem i would use jQuery + jQuery UI. I would create an absolutely positioned div and style it as you like.

Then using a a jquery hover function you will be able to make this div appear and disappear.

E.g.

```
$("#button").hover(
  function () {
    $("#hidden-div").fadeIn("fast");
  },
  function () {
    $("#hidden-div").fadeOut("fast");
  }
);
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing that I was going to do, if there wasn't a better solution. Since that's so easy anyway, I think I'll avoid adding another plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[qTip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) is a good plugin you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the method in jquery :

```
.toggle()
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Maybe that can help you out.